# Blank TIF image when using MATLAB TIFF class

Tags: image, image-processing, tiff, matlab

**strong text**I am trying to save a multi-page TIF file using the MATLAB TIFF class in 2012a by following the [example in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-123068.html#br_c_iz-1). My usage differs in that I am writing a 32-bit grayscale image with values ranging from approximately -10,000 to 200,000.

```
% Use 'a' for 'append' since this code is in a loop that writes each page.
% Note: 'fileName' is defined elsewhere and the file is created.
t = Tiff(fileName, 'a');

tagstruct.ImageLength = size(result, 2);
tagstruct.ImageWidth = size(result, 1);
tagstruct.Photometric = Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack;
tagstruct.SampleFormat = Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP;
tagstruct.Compression = Tiff.Compression.None;
tagstruct.BitsPerSample = 32;
tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = 1;
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky;
tagstruct.Software = 'MATLAB';
t.setTag(tagstruct);

% Viewing the data immediately before the 'write' operation shows it correct.
% imtool(result(:, :, j));
% Tools -> Adjust Contrast                       
t.write(result(:, :, j));

t.close();
```

The output image, as inspected by both MATLAB and ImageJ, is the correct size and has the correct metadata, but all values are zero.

**Update:**

MATLAB's documentation is somewhat sparse for the TIFF class, which itself is a wrapper for the [LibTIFF library](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/). The [official TIFF Specification Version 6](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf) denotes the full list of required fields for each TIF image type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [example of MATLAB documentation: Exporting to images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-123068.html#br_c_iz-1) there is one line which you don't have in your code:

```
tagstruct.RowsPerStrip = 16
```

So maybe missing `RowsPerStrip` field of `tagstruct` is the cause of the image of all zeros.

Comment: You are correct. The MATLAB documentation does not read (to me) in a way that specifies 'RowsPerStrip' as a required field. Adding the entry did create a TIF file with usable data. Thank you.